# Define function in scala using DataFrame type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would have a simple question...
I try to use a function that ate a dataframe as argument and returns another dataframe

I do:

```
val get_nb_previous_offre : ((DataFrame) => (DataFrame)) = (arg1: DataFrame) => {
   // create new_df using arg1 (=DataFrame I pass in parameter)
      new_df    
}
```

I get the error:

```
<console>:32: error: not found: type DataFrame
   val get_nb_previous_offre : ((DataFrame) => (DataFrame)) = (arg1: DataFrame) => {
```

Is there a librairy I have to import to use DataFrame as a type for my function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you need to import this type :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

Comment: Alternativly this comon Scala syntax also works:   `import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame}` . Also for anyone coming here and previously coding in PySpark, make sure to stick to camel case convention to avoid exception.